# Compare two list of property of id and remove only that object from list1 not remove from list2 then merge into single list in java

Tags: java, collections

```
List<ManageEventDTO> yourUpcomingEventsList = eventsDao.findYourUpcomingEvents(members, LocalDate.now());
List<ManageEventDTO> yourUpcomingRecurrenceEvents = eventsDao.findYourUpcomingRecurrenceEvents(members, LocalDate.now());
```

How to Compare two DTO list based on id property and remove only that object from this yourUpcomingEventsList and it will not remove from yourUpcomingRecurrenceEvents. In this list duplicate is required.

After the removed duplicate object from yourUpcomingEventsList i want merge this list with yourUpcomingRecurrenceEvents and create new List.

1.yourUpcomingEventsList

```
[
    {
      "id": 339,
      "recurrenceEventId": null,
      "eventName": "Magic Moments",
      "passport": true
    },
    {
      "id": 154,
      "recurrenceEventId": null,
      "eventName": "Women's Networking League Lunch",
      "passport": true
    },
    {
      "id": 155,
      "recurrenceEventId": null,
      "eventName": "Gingerbread",
      "passport": false
    },
    {
      "id": 156,
      "recurrenceEventId": null,
      "eventName": "Business Network",
      "passport": false
    },
    {
      "id": 163,
      "recurrenceEventId": null,
      "eventName": "Gingerbread",
      "passport": false
    },
    {
      "id": 164,
      "recurrenceEventId": null,
      "eventName": "Women's Networking League Lunch",
      "passport": false
    }
]
```

2.yourUpcomingRecurrenceEvents

```
[
    {
      "id": 339,
      "recurrenceEventId": 13,
      "eventName": "Magic Moments",
      "passport": true
    },
    {
      "id": 339,
      "recurrenceEventId": 14,
      "eventName": "Magic Moments",
      "passport": true
    },
    {
      "id": 336,
      "recurrenceEventId": 6,
      "eventName": "Networking Cigars & Drink",
      "passport": true
    },
    {
      "id": 336,
      "recurrenceEventId": 7,
      "eventName": "Networking Cigars & Drink",
      "passport": true
    },
    {
      "id": 335,
      "recurrenceEventId": 3,
      "eventName": "Party with Dance",
      "passport": true
    },
    {
      "id": 335,
      "recurrenceEventId": 4,
      "eventName": "Party with Dance",
      "passport": true
    },
    {
      "id": 337,
      "recurrenceEventId": 8,
      "eventName": "Monday MasterMind",
      "passport": true
    },
    {
      "id": 338,
      "recurrenceEventId": 11,
      "eventName": "Drink & smoke only for men",
      "passport": true
    }
  ]
```

3. I have try

```
            for (ManageEventDTO yourUpcomingRecurrence : yourUpcomingRecurrenceEvents) {
                if (yourUpcomingEvents.contains(yourUpcomingRecurrence.getId())) {
                    yourUpcomingEvents.remove(yourUpcomingRecurrence);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a set of `id`'s of `yourUpcomingRecurrenceEvents` then filter `yourUpcomingEventsList` list those do not exist in set and collect in new list. Then add new list into `yourUpcomingRecurrenceEvents`

```
Set<Integer> eventIds = yourUpcomingRecurrenceEvents.stream()
                                                    .map(e -> e.getId())
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<ManageEventDTO> newEvents = yourUpcomingEventsList.stream()
                                          .filter(e -> !eventIds.contains(e.getId()))
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
yourUpcomingRecurrenceEvents.addAll(newEvents);                      
                            .
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'toSet' in 'Collector' and Cannot resolve method 'toList' in 'Collector'    -   for these two line compilation error is shown